# Prevent setx to expand an environment variable?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, path

I can add to the `PATH` variable from the console using the following command:

```
setx PATH "%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%" /m
```

However, when I check the PATH variable afterwards the `JAVA_HOME` variable has been expanded so that the actual `PATH` looks like `X:\Path\To\Java\bin;...` instead of `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;...`. Is there a way to use setx like I do here without having the `JAVA_HOME` variable expanded?

Tried using double `%%` but that just gave me the expanded version with a percentage on each end. Also tried `\%`, but that just messed it up.

Answer (score 4):

The command shell escapes with the `^` character, so what you need is to escape the `%` characters like so: `^%`. Try this as a replacement command line:

`setx PATH ^%JAVA_HOME^%\bin;"%PATH%" /m`

Be careful though, where `%PATH%` is getting expanded.

**EDIT**

I think this is a safer way to do it. The first can be pasted right into a command prompt:

```
FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=2,*" %i IN (`REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path`) DO set origpath=%j
SET newpath=^%JAVA_HOME^%\bin;%origpath%
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /f /v Path_ /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%newpath%
```

And this version can be used in a batch file:

```
FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=2,*" %%i IN (`REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path`) DO set origpath=%%j
SET newpath=%%JAVA_HOME%%\bin;%origpath%
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /f /v Path_ /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%newpath%
```

In both cases, please test and be careful on production systems. I believe I got all the funky escaping correct, but I may have missed something. Also note the missing trailing `"` on the end of both line 3's is intentional. You should also be able to modify it to run against remote systems by prepending `\\HOSTNAME\` in front of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

Comment: So existing environment variables in PATH will be expanded as well? Is there a way to avoid that then? Would be nice to *only* append/prepend a value to PATH without changing anything existing in it :S

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do what you're asking with `setx`. What about if you instead read the existing `Path` value from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`, prepend your string to it, and write it back?

Comment: Can you do that from the console?

Comment: See my edits above, I think they may be a better approach.